# Chaining expression binding across isolated scopes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**How can I pass a function down through two directives with isolated scopes using expression binding?**

I have two directives in a parent-child relationship:

```
app.directive('parentDir', function(){
    return {
        scope:{
            parentData:'=',
            changeRouteParent:'&'
        },
        templateUrl:'mydir/parentTemplate.html'
    };
});

app.directive('childDir', function(){
    return {
        scope:{
            dirData:'=',
            changeRoute:'&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'mydir/childTemplate.html'
    };
});
```

In parent template:

```
<div class="parentDirClass">
    <a ng-click="changeRouteParent({newFoo:parentData.url})>fooLink</a>
    <div child-dir ng-repeat="child in parentData.childData" dir-data="child" change-route="???"></div>
</div>
```

In child template:

```
<div class="childDirClass">
  <a ng-click="changeRoute=({{newFoo:dirData.url}})">foolink</a>
</div>
```

Trying to use the directives together:

```
app.controller('exampleController', function($scope, $state){
    $scope.changeRoute = function(newFoo) {
        $state.go(newFoo);
    };
    $scope.theParentData = pData;
});

//parent data
pdata = {url:'/fooUrl',
         childData:[{url:'/whatever1'},{url:'/whatever2'}, {url:'/whatever3'}]};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="exampleController">
 <div parent-dir parent-data="pData" change-route-parent="changeRoute(newFoo???)"></div>
</div>
```

With one level of expression binding the solution seems easy as you can easily identify the variables being passed (`changeRoute=({{newFoo:dirData.url}})` in the child directive) but then moving up a level I have no variable to pass. How can I continue to pass `dirData.url` up the chain into the example controller to call `changeRoute` ?

Answer (score 3):

After some tinkering I found chaining can be achieved as follows --

When a bound expression is used in a template at the most-child directive: 
`childBoundExpression({variableFromChild:variableinIsolatedScope})`

Then, starting from the parent of the most-child directive:

`<div childDirective child-bound-expression="parentBoundExpression({variableToParent:variableFromChild}) ></div>`

For the nth parent use the above expression and repeat until you reach the top directive/html. Eventually the name of `variableToParent` must be the variable that will be passed to the function on your most-parent `$scope`

The most important bit is that **if you are passing the same variable from child to parent `variableToParent` and `variableFromChild` must be the same name.**